# Can I save data from php to json and MySQL database at the same time?

Tags: php

I am working on and android app where I have to show results.

Though I managed to show result in android from php and MySQL, but I want to save data which I get from html form to MySQL database and at the same time I want the same data to be saved in json file. Any help / guidance in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Note: I want data to be saved in both formats cause I only know how to fetch and show data in admin panel through saving data in MySQL database.

My form_action.php file

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
include_once("../config/db_connect.php");

?>
<title>Patient Information</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php include('container.php');?>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Add Draw</h2>       
    <div class="row well alert alert-success">      
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); // Error/Exception engine, always use E_ALL

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
        $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
        $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);
        $result1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['result1']);
        $result2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['result2']);
        $result3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['result3']);
        
        if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO result(date, time, result1, result2, result3) VALUES('".$date."', '".$time."', '".$result1."', '". $result2."', '".$result3."')")) {
            echo "Result added Successfully!";
        } else {
            echo "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
        }
    }

    
    ?>  
    </div>
        
</div>
<?php?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: What do you mean "saved in JSON file"? Where? Just dumped on the local filesystem? Uploaded somewhere? Why can't you generate JSON on-demand from the database if the data is the same?

Comment: Of course you can store data anywhere, any amount of times. But redundant data is a great recipe to end up with inconsistencies. So you probably shouldn't. (There are exceptions like backups for instance, but there it is clear which set of data has the lead in which cases.)

Comment: sir first i amde a admin panel where data save from form is saved in mysql database, then i also have to show the same data in android list view, and there i have to use search filter, and for that i was thinking if i save data in json file and then show it in android app,

Comment: Rescted sir  tadman, sorry i now understand your comment, thanks, as i am new to it, and i have little knowledge of PDO. If i am getting you right, if i use PDO will it be more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

`file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($_POST));`

will probably do the trick...

In general saving this for debugging purposes like that isn't really practical, an `error_log()` will probably help you out a lot better

Comment: Sit it worked perfect. But it also saving submit button value
{"date":"14\/02\/2021","time":"07:00 pm","result1":"8745","result2":"6524","result3":"1258","submit":"Submit"}

Comment: Yeah, that'll save everything in the superglobal, including 'submit'. A quick fix would be to use unset($_POST['submit'); before the file_put_contents, but if I were you I'd look into a different solution for your problem

Comment: Sir thanks a lot, but there is a little problem, it is only saving last record in json, how can i get all records saved in database, as i will then load this json in listview android, and over there i have applied a date filter on it. or in simple saying how can i populate json file with every new record and keeping the old record in it.

Comment: You could do that if you really wanted to, but if I were you, i'd follow @tadman 's suggestion to generate the json on-demand.

Comment: thank you sir, i am doing json on demand in android using volley and showing it in android recycler view. but then i cant place search filter on it over there. where as when i populate list with json file from a link then search filter works over there